Adding Day Information to Expanded DataFrame in Python (Pandas)
I have the following pandas DataFrame (df1):
Python
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'EMPRESA': ['AIR', 'LATAM'],
    'NUMERO_DE_VUELO': [901, 504],
    'DIAS_SEMANA': ['1237', '12'],
    'ORIGEN': ['SCL', 'LIM'],
    'DESTINO': ['MIA', 'PUQ'],
    'HORA_DESPEGUE': ['21:55', '18:55'],
    'INICIO_RANGO': ['03-jun-24', '04-jun-24'],
    'FINAL_RANGO': ['08-jun-24', '07-jun-24']
})

Explanation:
Each number in the 'DIAS_SEMANA' column represents a day of the week, with 1 being Monday and 7 being Sunday.
I created another DataFrame (df2) from df1 using a function called expand_date_ranges:
def expand_date_ranges(X):
    df_list = []

    for i in range(len(X)): # para cada fila en rango se expande utilizando la cantidad de días
        start_date = X.loc[i, 'INICIO_RANGO']
        end_date = X.loc[i, 'FINAL_RANGO']
        date_range = pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date)

        for date in date_range: #para cada día expandido se añade la info de las otras columnas creando una lista y luego añadiendola en cada fila
            day_of_week = date.weekday() + 1  # Lunes = 1, Domingo = 7
            df_list.append({
                'FECHA': date,
                'DIA': '',
                'NUMERO_VUELO': X.loc[i, 'NUMERO_DE_VUELO'],
                'HORA': X.loc[i, 'HORA_DESPEGUE'],
                'ORIGEN': X.loc[i, 'ORIGEN'],
                'DESTINO': X.loc[i, 'DESTINO'],
                'LINEA_AEREA': X.loc[i, 'EMPRESA'],
                'DIA_SEMANA': day_of_week
            })

    df_expanded = pd.DataFrame(df_list)

    return df_expanded

The function works as intended, but the 'DIA' column in df2 is missing information. This column should indicate whether there is a flight for that specific day based on the information in 'DIAS_SEMANA'.
Question:
How can I efficiently add this information to the 'DIA' column in df2 using Python and pandas?
Additional Information:
I've included a snippet of the expand_date_ranges function for context, but the complete code might not be relevant to the specific question.
I'm open to alternative approaches or suggestions for clarity or efficiency.
Desired Outcome:
I want the 'DIA' column in df2 to contain a value (e.g., "YES" or "NO") indicating if there's a flight for that day based on the corresponding day code in 'DIAS_SEMANA'.

Instead of iterating over date ranges, you can create them as values in the dataframe using apply on axis=1, and then explode them in different rows. This is more efficient and will retain all of the data in the original dataframe.
To get the new column 'DIA', again use apply on axis=1 to compare columns 'DIA_SEMANA' and 'DIAS_SEMANA' for each row.
df1["FECHA"] = df1.apply(
    lambda row: pd.date_range(
        pd.to_datetime(row["INICIO_RANGO"]), pd.to_datetime(row["FINAL_RANGO"])
    ),
    axis=1,
)
df1 = df1.explode("FECHA")
df1["DIA_SEMANA"] = (df1["FECHA"].dt.weekday + 1).astype(str)

df1["DIA"] = df1.apply(
    lambda row: "YES" if row["DIA_SEMANA"] in row["DIAS_SEMANA"] else "NO", axis=1
)

  EMPRESA  NUMERO_DE_VUELO DIAS_SEMANA ORIGEN DESTINO HORA_DESPEGUE INICIO_RANGO FINAL_RANGO      FECHA DIA_SEMANA  DIA
0     AIR              901        1237    SCL     MIA         21:55    03-jun-24   08-jun-24 2024-06-03          1  YES
0     AIR              901        1237    SCL     MIA         21:55    03-jun-24   08-jun-24 2024-06-04          2  YES
0     AIR              901        1237    SCL     MIA         21:55    03-jun-24   08-jun-24 2024-06-05          3  YES
0     AIR              901        1237    SCL     MIA         21:55    03-jun-24   08-jun-24 2024-06-06          4   NO
0     AIR              901        1237    SCL     MIA         21:55    03-jun-24   08-jun-24 2024-06-07          5   NO
0     AIR              901        1237    SCL     MIA         21:55    03-jun-24   08-jun-24 2024-06-08          6   NO
1   LATAM              504          12    LIM     PUQ         18:55    04-jun-24   07-jun-24 2024-06-04          2  YES
1   LATAM              504          12    LIM     PUQ         18:55    04-jun-24   07-jun-24 2024-06-05          3   NO
1   LATAM              504          12    LIM     PUQ         18:55    04-jun-24   07-jun-24 2024-06-06          4   NO
1   LATAM              504          12    LIM     PUQ         18:55    04-jun-24   07-jun-24 2024-06-07          5   NO


For a vectorial approach (except the last step), you can repeat the rows, then increment the days, finally convert to weekday and test the inclusion in your list of days:
tmp = (df1[['INICIO_RANGO', 'FINAL_RANGO']]
       .apply(pd.to_datetime, format='%d-%b-%y')
       )

n = tmp['FINAL_RANGO'].sub(tmp['INICIO_RANGO']).dt.days

out = df1.loc[df1.index.repeat(n+1)]

out['FECHA'] = tmp['INICIO_RANGO'].add(pd.to_timedelta(out.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), unit='D'))

out['DIA_SEMANA'] = out['FECHA'].dt.weekday+1

out['DIA'] = ['YES' if str(wd) in ds else 'NO'
              for wd, ds in zip(out['FECHA'], out['DIAS_SEMANA'])]

Output:
  EMPRESA  NUMERO_DE_VUELO DIAS_SEMANA ORIGEN DESTINO HORA_DESPEGUE INICIO_RANGO FINAL_RANGO      FECHA  DIA_SEMANA  DIA
0     AIR              901        1237    SCL     MIA         21:55    03-jun-24   08-jun-24 2024-06-03           1  YES
0     AIR              901        1237    SCL     MIA         21:55    03-jun-24   08-jun-24 2024-06-04           2  YES
0     AIR              901        1237    SCL     MIA         21:55    03-jun-24   08-jun-24 2024-06-05           3  YES
0     AIR              901        1237    SCL     MIA         21:55    03-jun-24   08-jun-24 2024-06-06           4   NO
0     AIR              901        1237    SCL     MIA         21:55    03-jun-24   08-jun-24 2024-06-07           5   NO
0     AIR              901        1237    SCL     MIA         21:55    03-jun-24   08-jun-24 2024-06-08           6   NO
1   LATAM              504          12    LIM     PUQ         18:55    04-jun-24   07-jun-24 2024-06-04           2  YES
1   LATAM              504          12    LIM     PUQ         18:55    04-jun-24   07-jun-24 2024-06-05           3   NO
1   LATAM              504          12    LIM     PUQ         18:55    04-jun-24   07-jun-24 2024-06-06           4   NO
1   LATAM              504          12    LIM     PUQ         18:55    04-jun-24   07-jun-24 2024-06-07           5   NO

